# How to dynamically select a pytest fixture?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

```
import pytest


@pytest.fixture()
def fixture1(fixture_a):
    print('In fixture 1')
    <do>
    step a
    step b
    <end>
    return <some object1> 



@pytest.fixture()
def fixture2(fixture_b):
    print('In fixture 2')
    <do>
    step x
    step y
    <end>
    return <some object2> 


def decide():
    a = 1
    if a == 1:
        return fixture1: Object1
    else:
        return fixture2: Object2


def test_me():
    res = decide()
    assert res == Object
```

I have two fixtures arg1 and arg2, now I want to return one of the fixture to the test but this has to be dynamic selection based on a condition. How to do this?

UPDATE: The fixtures arg1 and arg2 have a chain of dependency and they are being used in different tests.

Also, decide function needs to be used in multiple tests.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the `arg1` and `arg2` to `test` and test the condition itself.

```
def decide():
    a = 1
    if a == 1:
        return 1
    else:
        return 2

def test_me(fixture1, fixture2):
    arg = decide()
    if arg == 1:
        assert fixture1 == 1
    else:
        assert fixture2 == 2
```

Comment: But I have multiple tests which needs this. Updating all the tests might not be a great idea.

Comment: okay, I added a separate function to return the value to decide the arg. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I have updated the question code closer to the usecase that I am trying to solve. In my case, I cannot really pull out the logic out of fixture1 and fixture2. These fixtures also use other fixtures so implementing the chain of dependency will be painful. Is there a way to implement this without touching fixture1 and fixture2 and still be able to pass one of them that to the test based on a certain condition?

Comment: In my answer, I am not changing anything in the fixture. You have to just pass those fixture in the test function and then return values instead of returning function object from the decide function.

Comment: You have pulled out the logic from fixture1 and fixture1 and used that as a return value in decide. In my case, it will be a painful change to implement the logic of fixtures in decide function as there is dependency of fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that can help - having fixture builder what runs functions(convert fixtures A,B to functions) in case of condition:

```
def arg1():
    print('In arg 1')
    return 1

def arg2():
    print('In arg 2')
    return 2

@pytest.fixture
def env_builder():
    if condition:
        return arg1()
    else
        return arg2()

def test_smth(env_builder):
   assert 2 == env_builder
```

your condition is up to you, os.getenv('environment'), or might positional cli argument while running tests